# How to check input tag have only tag(<br/>) inside as value using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Check input tag which have value only as  `<br/>` tag  inside as value using jQuery

I am using an htmlEditor in my project, sometimes user just press enter key only in textarea field. It will get as `<br/><br/><br/><br/>` as value when saving.
I want to avoid this tags when saving.

How to validate this in jquery ?

If any other characters like  `<br/>Just <br/> Example <br/>` is present then I want to save it with break tag itself.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using a regex like this would help.

```
/^(\<br\/>)+$/.test($("textarea").val());
```

Comment: Thank you , It works fine. I am not familar with regex . Can you please explain your regex function

Comment: so a regex basically allows you to check a string for a given pattern.  There are some great tutorials here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html - I also use http://rubular.com/ to help me draft regular expessions.

Answer (score 1):

Clean it like this:

```
// Get the HTML and remove <br /> variants
var htmlCleaned = $('#MyTextArea').val().replace(/<br\s?\/?>/, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer [LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZMsh3/1/)

```
var divTag = $("div"); 
var nDivTag = $(divTag[0].outerHTML); 
$("br", nDivTag).remove(); 
alert(nDivTag.html());
```